# d3: My paths seem to be doubling up and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, chaining

I've been powering into D3, looking at samples by Mike Bostock and anyone else I can find, and brushing up on the documentation, and even have a book by Scott Murray on Interactive Data Visualization - a book on D3.

I'm currently working on a connection chart, and I'm starting to understand enough to take this all beyond just changing out the data from a sample, but I am running into some problems still that I can't figure out.

Here's my sample link,
http://www.nogumallowed.com/test4.php

And here's my data,
http://www.nogumallowed.com/userImages/friendData1.JSON

This sample has seven people and the rest are all likes from facebook. The chart shows the intersections of the likes between users. My problem is with the paths, it seems that I'm adding double the paths necessary, and I'm not sure why. I'm still getting familiar with the enter function, as well as the practice of selectiong something that isn't in the DOM to place it in the DOM.

Just doing some counting from the code, there should be 115 paths, but I keep generating 230 paths.

I'm still new enough to d3 that for the life of me, I can't figure this one out right now.

What I'd like to accomplish... When creating the gradients, the starting position should be blue when it's connected to a user, and then another various color for all of the likes. From the code I've put together, I don't believe there should ever be something that isn't a user start with blue, and a user should never have a line conencted to them that isn't blue at the base, but as you can see, i'm running into that.

---

Edit: I've found that my problem isn't with grabbing the incorrect paths, it's having connections with A and B, and not knowing this point comes first in the path. If I want the path at connection A to always be blue, and the connection at path B to always be green, I don't have a way to detect that beyond this path simple has a source of A and a target of B, I don't know which will really come first. I'm updating my example script to a lighter version to see this.

In this example, the 7 user names should always have blue coming from them, and everything else should always have red coming from them, but as you can see, that is definitely not always the case. This is where I am currently at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data file actually contains 230 links:

```
var n = 0;
classes.forEach(function(d) { n = n + d.imports.length; });
// n == 230
```

Also you have items with the same name in the data (e.g. classes[8] abd classes[115]) - may be it leads to some confusiion

Comment: I think then it's safe to say I'm likely structuring my data incorrectly. My basic understanding was that I needed a JSON record for every item, and then in the imports, those would have to match up with primary items. Am I pretty off on that? In the design I have here, connections should only come from records in the "friends" category, and reach out to other elements, but it seems like they're doubling back.

Comment: I cleaned up my data, I had made a change that would have eliminated duplicates, that's not functioning again

Comment: still having the same issues though

Comment: Why do you think you have extra links now? According to your data file there are 203 imports - and you've got 203 path.link elements.

Comment: The problem I'm having is more along the lines of... I currently am able to grab my paths, and I'm creating the gradients for them, since I want the color gradients to be specific to the type of connection. The problem is, each path has a source of A and a target of B. Then I place an initial start color and an End color. I'm clearly going about this wrong though because I've been assuming that A always connects to B, and never the other way around, which seems to be the case. I need to find a way to make sure that the source or destination are the first or second points on the path.

Comment: In your updated example it looks that A is always 'friends' nodes. So you can just set the start and stop color of the gradient based on the category of the source.category and target.category. You actually do it already that way - just needs some finalizing